# Salesforce1 Publisher Button Disappears

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, publisher

My **Salesforce1** apps publisher button in the bottom right hand corner disappeared as soon as I made a custom visualforce page the landing page for the app. Has anyone else ever had this problem?

Thanks Joe

Comment: I think once you override the page publisher button can't be shown.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your visualforce page which overrides the "New" action on the opportunity is NOT marked as "Available for Salesforce mobile apps".

Setup -> Develop -> Pages -> Set "[image: Available for Salesforce mobile apps]"

Additionally, if you are using record types, make sure your user has access to the record types or else the publisher button won't be visible.